# Is there a way of differentiating between Custom error pages and default error pages for webpages?

Tags: c#, http-status-code-404

I am just wondering if there is a method to test whether a 404 error page which is returned from a server is the default error page for that server (I'm mainly thinking about the default 404 page returned from IIS) and a custom one which has been created to be site specific?

When I make a request to the server a 404 error is returned. Sometimes the content-length in the header is 0 (which is usually then handled by the browser) otherwise an error page is returned. This means that the content-length is now no longer 0 and therefore I can't easily differentiate between what is custom and what is just the plain old default page.

I have considered a few content analysis methods, most of which are memory heavy (especially for larger pages) and I wondered if anybody had found a neat trick to compare two webpages like this.

Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just compare the HTML of the page that's returned.  More than likely, you are receiving the page as a simple string.  Just compare the string you receive to one you've stored in your code, like the code  I list below.

The IIS7 default 404 page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>404 - File or directory not found.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>404 - File or directory not found.</h2>
  <h3>The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```